# Error in nls singular gradient R

Tags: r, curve-fitting

I have a data frame like this

```
 time     WT   WTIC ATIC   RHIC esaIC          k  uIC
1 0.00 25.191 25.191 21.4 67.925 25.49 0.06152572 3.53
2 0.05 25.186 25.191 21.4 67.925 25.49 0.06152572 3.53
3 0.10 25.179 25.191 21.4 67.925 25.49 0.06152572 3.53
4 0.15 25.168 25.191 21.4 67.925 25.49 0.06152572 3.53
5 0.20 25.158 25.191 21.4 67.925 25.49 0.06152572 3.53
6 0.25 25.147 25.191 21.4 67.925 25.49 0.06152572 3.53
```

which I would like to fit using this non linear function

```
f <- function(x,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,par1,par2,par3) {  
      Tinf <- a2 - (par2*(1-a3/100)*a4)/(1+par2*a5*a4)
      kC <-par1*sqrt(a6)
      V <- kC + par3
      tau <- 1/(V*(1+par2*a5*a4))

      func <- a1 -(a1-Tinf)*(1-exp(-x/tau))
      return(func)
}
```

However, when using `nls`

```
nls(WT~f(time,WTIC,ATIC,RHIC,esaIC,k,uIC,par1,par2,par3), data=df, start=c(par1=1, par2=1,par3=1))
```

I get this error

```
Error in nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts) : 
  singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates
```

I tried to change the starting values of the parameters but I still get the same error. Any help?

Comment: How many data points are you trying to fit? Perhaps you are overparametrizing your model. In which case, you should get more data or specify less parameters. If the problem is purely in starting values, you could use brute force search to find them. Have you seen this thread? http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Error-quot-singular-gradient-matrix-at-initial-parameter-estimates-quot-in-nls-td1745042.html

Comment: I'm having trouble reproducing your problem. Is the variable "a" in the denominator of "tau" a typo or is it defined elsewhere in your code? Likewise for the variable "r" in kC. Furthermore kC seems to be defined within "f" but then it is not used anywhere else in calculating the return value "func".

Comment: @RomanLuštrik in each dataset there are 300 points ..

Comment: @frank2165 sorry for the typos I have corrected it

Answer (score 4):

This "Singular Gradient" error is a drawback of the "nls" function.
"optim" behaves better:

```
df <- read.table( text = 
 ' time     WT   WTIC ATIC   RHIC esaIC          k  uIC
  "0.00" "25.191" "25.191" "21.4" "67.925" "25.49" "0.06152572" "3.53"
  "0.05" "25.186" "25.191" "21.4" "67.925" "25.49" "0.06152572" "3.53"
  "0.10" "25.179" "25.191" "21.4" "67.925" "25.49" "0.06152572" "3.53"
  "0.15" "25.168" "25.191" "21.4" "67.925" "25.49" "0.06152572" "3.53"
  "0.20" "25.158" "25.191" "21.4" "67.925" "25.49" "0.06152572" "3.53"
  "0.25" "25.147" "25.191" "21.4" "67.925" "25.49" "0.06152572" "3.53"',
   header = TRUE )


f <- function(x,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,par1,par2,par3) {  
  Tinf <- a2 - (par2*(1-a3/100)*a4)/(1+par2*a5*a4)
  kC <-par1*sqrt(a6)
  V <- kC + par3
  tau <- 1/(V*(1+par2*a5*a4))

  func <- a1 -(a1-Tinf)*(1-exp(-x/tau))
  return(func)
}

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Essentially the same as f:

g <- function(v){f(v[1],v[2],v[3],v[4],v[5],v[6],v[7],v[8],v[9],v[10])}

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# The function we want to minimize:

squaredError <- function(par)
{
  sum((df$"WT"-apply(cbind(df[,-2],par[1],par[2],par[3]),1,g))^2)
}

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Optimization of the parameters:

opt <- optim( par    = c(1,1,1),
              fn     = squaredError,
              method = "BFGS" )

#----------------------------------------------------------------
# Result:

opt

squaredError(opt$par + c( 1, 0, 0)*1e-3 )
squaredError(opt$par + c(-1, 0, 0)*1e-3 )
squaredError(opt$par + c( 0, 1, 0)*1e-3 )
squaredError(opt$par + c( 0,-1, 0)*1e-3 )
squaredError(opt$par + c( 0, 0, 1)*1e-3 )
squaredError(opt$par + c( 0, 0,-1)*1e-3 )
```

.

```
> opt
$par
[1] -0.04261273 -0.23600921  0.44504195

$value
[1] 4.572781e-05

$counts
function gradient 
     137      100 

$convergence
[1] 1

$message
NULL


> squaredError(opt$par + c( 1, 0, 0)*1e-3 )
[1] 4.581051e-05

> squaredError(opt$par + c(-1, 0, 0)*1e-3 )
[1] 4.583096e-05

> squaredError(opt$par + c( 0, 1, 0)*1e-3 )
[1] 4.900303e-05

> squaredError(opt$par + c( 0,-1, 0)*1e-3 )
[1] 4.939846e-05

> squaredError(opt$par + c( 0, 0, 1)*1e-3 )
[1] 4.57487e-05

> squaredError(opt$par + c( 0, 0,-1)*1e-3 )
[1] 4.575957e-05
>
```